# Groupby pandas dataframe two columns with same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to `groupby` two column with the same value in 'A' and 'B' and make a `cumsum` based on which column is located that value.

Example of grouped dataframe for a values

```
   A  B  ValueA  ValueB
0  b  a       1       3
1  c  a       2       2
2  a  b       2       4
```

Now, if the value is in column 'A' consider ValueA to `cumsum` if the value is in column 'B' consider ValueB to `cumsum`

EDIT: I would to perform `shift().rolling()` just like `cumsum`, I tried to put it after groupby but result is not correct.

Code

```
from numpy.core.numeric import NaN

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : ['b','c','a','c','a','c','b','c'],
    'B': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b','c','a','a','b'],
    'ValueA':[1,2,2,1,2,4,7,1],
    'ValueB':[3,2,4,3,1,2,4,5]
})
print(df)

df[['sumA','sumB']] = (
    df[['ValueA','ValueB']].stack(dropna=False)
      .groupby(df[['A','B']].stack().tolist())
      .cumsum()
      .unstack()
)
print(df)

#groupby(...).shift().rolling(2, min_periods=2).sum()

df['Expected_Shift_RollingA'] = [NaN,NaN,5,NaN,4,2,7,5]
df['Expected_Shift_RollingB'] = [NaN,NaN,NaN,5,3,4,4,10]
print(df)
```

Comment: kindly add more explanation on what you expect

Comment: @sammywemmy Post edited

Comment: Can you explain how you get values in `ExpectedSumA`, please?

Comment: @Corralien it is a cumulative sum of values in A and B with his relative value in ValueA and ValueB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `stack` the values columns, use `groupby` on the column A-B stacked, then `cumsum` and `unstack` to be back original shape

```
df[['sumA','sumB']] = (
    df[['ValueA','ValueB']].stack()
      .groupby(df[['A','B']].stack().tolist())
      .cumsum()
      .unstack()
)
print(df)
   A  B  ValueA  ValueB  sumA  sumB
0  b  a       1       3     1     3
1  c  a       2       2     2     5
2  a  b       2       4     7     5
3  c  b       1       3     3     8
```

EDIT: after reviewing the original data, some Values are missing, so one need to adjust the above method.

By either filling the missing values by 0.

```
df[['ValueA','ValueB']].fillna(0).stack()
  .groupby(...
```

or keeping the `nan` while `stack` so.

```
df[['ValueA','ValueB']].stack(dropna=False)
  .groupby(...
```

Comment: I tried to use this to my original dataframe but I got `ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional`

Comment: I tried it but I got another error `KeyError: ...` with the value in corresponding column A

Comment: `KeyError` does not show the column name, but the first value inside it

Comment: I did not remove `stack` for values columns, I have only strings in A and B

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236200/discussion-between-luka-and-ben-t).