# Shift rolling moving average on two columns grouped Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to `groupby` two column with the same value in 'A' and 'B' and make a `shift().rolling()` based on which column is located that value.

df

```
   s  A  B  ValueA  ValueB
0  1  b  a       1       3
1  1  c  a       2       2
2  0  a  b       2       4
3  0  c  b       1       3
4  0  a  c       2       1
5  0  c  a       4       2
6  0  b  a       7       4
7  0  c  b       1       5
```

Now, if the value is in column 'A' consider ValueA to `shift().rolling()` if the value is in column 'B' consider ValueB to `shift().rolling()`

I tried this code but the result is not correct

Code

```
from numpy.core.numeric import NaN

df = pd.DataFrame({
    's' : [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    'A' : ['b','c','a','c','a','c','b','c'],
    'B': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b','c','a','a','b'],
    'ValueA':[1,2,2,1,2,4,7,1],
    'ValueB':[3,2,4,3,1,2,4,5]
})
print(df)

df[['sumA','sumB']] = df.groupby(['A','B'])[['ValueA','ValueB']].shift().rolling(2, min_periods=2).sum()
print(df)
```

Expected Output

```
  ValueA    ValueB
0   NaN     NaN
1   NaN     NaN
2   NaN     NaN
3   NaN     NaN
4   NaN     NaN
5   2.0     4.0
6   7.0     4.0
7   5.0     10.0
```

Comment: Please explain the logic of your output.

Comment: The initial dataframe is grouped by values in "A" and "B" in this case values are a,b,c. Then for `shift().rolling()` if the current value is in 'A' in 'ExpectedRollingA' will be the result and considering the current value in previous cells if is in 'A' `shift().rolling()` takes value from 'ValueA',  is in 'B' `shift().rolling()` takes value from 'ValueB'

Comment: This doesn't match the provided output. Can you break down the calculation or explain *what* you try to achieve (not *how*)?

Comment: Please clarify your explanation. At the moment, it makes no sense. The example data that is given is described as "example of grouped dataframe for "a" values": what does that mean? Is there another initial input we should be aware of? Can you describe how you arrive at one of the values for your expected result? For example, why is the first non-NaN value of your expected rollingA 5 (why is `df['ExpectedRollingA'].iloc[2] == 5`)?

Comment: @PierreD sorry, Expected result is for `shift().rolling().sum()` not `mean()` however,  `df['ExpectedRollingA'].iloc[2] == 5` beacuse `df['A'].iloc[2] == "a"` and according to `shift().rolling().sum()` I want to consider previous values of 'a' in col 'ValueB' if 'a' is in column 'B' , in my first example I show what I would to groupby

Comment: @mozway I am trying to get rolling sum of previous values in A or B column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried non loop version, but `shift` doesn't keep group devisions.

(Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68848666/8664422) answer)

```py
output_df = pd.DataFrame()
for _, grp in df[['ValueA','ValueB']].stack().groupby(df[['A','B']].stack().tolist()):
    sub_df = grp.shift().rolling(2, min_periods=2).sum().unstack()
    output_df = output_df.combine_first(sub_df)
output_df
```

Outputs:

```
|    |   ValueA |   ValueB |
|---:|---------:|---------:|
|  0 |      nan |      nan |
|  1 |      nan |      nan |
|  2 |        5 |      nan |
|  3 |      nan |        5 |
|  4 |        4 |        3 |
|  5 |        2 |        4 |
|  6 |        7 |        4 |
|  7 |        5 |       10 |
```

Comment: Thanks! And how if I would groupby by column 's' as well?

Comment: what is the expected output for `s`?

Comment: Post edited, check it. I tried to add `groupby(df['s'])` after `grp` but does not work, returns all NaN values